# What is the :nth() pseudo-class selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the definition of the `:nth` pseudo class ?

I can't find any jQuery or CSS documentation on it, but it seems to exist:

```
var $list = $('<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>');

$list.find('li:nth(2)').text();
```

Returns: `"3"`,

While:

```
 $list.find('li:nth-of-type(2)').text();
 $list.find('li:nth-child(2)').text();
```

both return `"2"`

What is this pseudo class? Can someone point me to some documentation on it?

Comment: @Zenith, thank's for the thorough explanation. I figured it was some sort of non-standard selector. I just couldn't find the source of it.

Comment: @user2369736, please stop trying to edit this question. Your suggested edits are changing the context of my question. Also, `.text()` returns a string, not a number, as you are implying with your edit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### What is the :nth() selector?

Contrary  to other answers, `:nth()` is **not** a CSS pseudo-class selector.

It's a little-known positional selector used in the [**Sizzle engine**](http://sizzlejs.com/):

> `:nth:` Finds the `nth` element on the page.

You'll find the above definition [**here in the Github documentation for Sizzle**](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#wiki-selectors).

### Why is it selecting different elements to :nth-child()/:nth-of-type()?

The reason that `nth()` and your other selectors select different elements is because `nth()` is a **zero-based index** selector, while the CSS selectors are **one-based index** selectors.

It's understandable how this can be confusing as most would assume that `nth()` would keep some kind of consistency with the similarly-named CSS pseudo class selectors such as `nth-child()` and `nth-of-type()` - however, as mentioned, they aren't actually related.

### So, :nth()'s functionality is actually closer to :eq() then?

Yes. In fact, it seems as though [**nth() is exactly the same as eq()**](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/01318877a96ffe44bb82b514e77e0d18fb709b38/sizzle.js#L1382):

```
Expr.pseudos["nth"] = Expr.pseudos["eq"];
```

[**This old mailing list conversation**](http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg13567.html) (2007) implies John Resig planned to remove the `:nth()` selector due to this:

> "I've searched the groups but I can't seem to find any related talk on
>   this. What, if any, is the difference between using `:eq(n)` and
>   `:nth(n)`? I'd like to know before I start standardizing on one or the
>   other. Thanks." **- Matt Penner**
>
> "They're the same, so you can use whichever you prefer. From jquery.js: `nth: "m[3]-0==i",` `eq: "m[3]-0==i"`" **- Karl Swedberg**
>
> "Huh... I should probably nuke `:nth()`." **- John Resig**

But, as you've noticed, the removal of the `:nth()` selector never materialised (as of 2013, anyway).

### **Example usage:**

**HTML:**

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('p:nth(2)').text(); // Returns 3 as zero-based index.
$('p:eq(2)').text(); // Returns 3 as zero-based index.
$('p:nth-child(2)').text(); // Returns 2 as one-based index.
$('p:nth-of-type(2)').text(); // Returns 2 as one-based index.
```

[**jsFiddle version here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KHzhq/1/)